# Spring Security: Ignore login page by using a special URL parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I currently have a setup that looks something like this:

**spring-security.xml:**

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login"
                default-target-url="/main.html"
                authentication-failure-url="/failedLogin"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout.html" logout-success-url="/login" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="foo" password="bar" authorities="ROLE_USER" />                
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This all seems to work as expected, however, in special situations I want the login page to be bypassed if the user passes in a special token.  So currently, if the user goes to a url such as `/dog`, they will see the login page and if they pass in the credentials of `foo/bar` then they will be logged in and see the page corresponding to `/dog`.

I want the ability to use a URL such as `/dog?token=abcd` which will bypass the login screen and take them directly to the page corresponding to `/dog`.  If they provide an invalid token then they would just see an access denied page.

Comment: Security FAIL -- Why on earth do you want such a back door?

Comment: It's something similar to this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830571/spring-security-bypass-login-form.  The token is unique and generated based on an algorithm and isn't so much a static string like 'abcd' each time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Spring Security the scenario you want to cover is described [in reference manual, chapter *Pre-Authentication Scenarios*](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#preauth).

Basically you have to:

- create custom filter by extending [`AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.html) or choosing one of its implementations,
- register custom filter `<custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="yourPreAuthFilter" />`,
- implement or choose one of implemented [`AuthenticationUserDetailsService`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/AuthenticationUserDetailsService.html)s,
- register the service in `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` (with `<property name="yourPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">`).

**EDIT**: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9919988/708434) OP shows his way of implementig custom `PRE_AUTH_FILTER`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried doing those things you mentioned along with the link to the OP but I still had troubles :( I then used bits and pieces of what you mentioned and the other OP and ended up using PRE_AUTH_FILTER custom-filter which references a class implementing a plain javax.servlet.Filter and put in the relevent code to authenticate if the token url parameter was found when there was no authentication object found in the SecurityContextHolder.